# Getting Errno 2 when i'm creating my first code

Tags: python

This is my first time creating a code and I downloaded anaconda to support python and my first code was print('hello world') on sublime text and it was successful till to that point but when I opened my command prompt or my anaconda prompt to open the file i get the and [Errno 2] no such file or directory.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqewL.png)

Answer (score 0):

#### Your command prompt is in `C:\Users\Jeeiivas\Desktop`, but your code is at `C:\Users\Jeeiivas\OneDrive\Desktop`

Ok, that is placed in different directory. Use:

```sh
cd ../OneDrive/Desktop
```

And then

```
py myexample.py
```

Comment: For the first time, i realized that i can use 'py' instead of 'python'.